# What's the best hash function for a hex string?

Tags: c++, hash, hex

I'm looking to encode a set of hexadecimal values stored in strings using a hash function. Since the hex ''alphabet'' is composed of only 16 letters, what would be the best hash algorithm with the least amount of collisions?

Comment: `atoi(str);` or it's equivalent in c++ would be collision free up to MAX_INT.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen collision free up to MAX_INT, and undefined behaviour with no way to do meaningful error recovery above that.  This is why we have strtol() nowadays.  Please don't recommend using atoi().

Comment: There is no reason to believe that _any well-known general hash function_ such as djb2 or murmur (to name two simple examples) will not perform well for hex strings, or at least will not perform any worse than any other hash. Ultra-short keys (1-3 bytes) always hash badly, not much one can do about that, and anything reasonable works reasonably well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a too general question, as you left out any constraints on the hash function, and/or what you're going to do with the hashes. (On a side note, hashing isn't an encoding)
That being said, having an alphabet of 16 letters, you need 4 bit to store each (i.e. you could build a XOR sum over each two letters crammed into a single byte, to get an 8-bit hash.
Of course, that can be extended to any other word length, too (but you left out too much information)

for instance like this:

> `uint8_t`
>   `hexhash(const char *str)`
>   `{`
>           `uint8_t res = 0;`
>           `while (*str && *(str+1)) {`
>                   `res ^= (fromchar(*str) << 4) | fromchar(*(str+1));`
>                   `str += 2;` //EDIT: forgot this in my original reply
>           `}`
>           `return res;`
>   `}`

(where 'fromchar' is a function to return 0 for '0', 1 for '1', ..., 15 for 'f')